# I am so confused with All-In of Limit Holdem

Tags: texas-hold-em, all-in

I am so confused with All-In of Limit Holdem. I searched the answer but I could not find any.... Could you please anyone explain me the rules of 
Call, Raise, and Complete when the amount of All-in is

1) less than the full raise amount
2) more than the full raise

I read some threads similar to this question but I could not understand those.

Regards,
MMW

Comment: You've asked several questions here and not given adequate details for any of them. Are you asking how to calculate the side pots, or who can reraise after an all-in, etc.?Pick a question, describe it exactly, and we'll answer that. Then pick another question, etc. I can give you one simplifying hint: which betting round you're on is not relevant--the rules are the same for every round.

Comment: You can always participate in an all-in, but you can only win equal amount of chips from the other players stacks as you've put out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A player cannot win more from each other player than they themselves have staked. If an all-in bet is insufficient to call, whatever amount is un-called, and all future raises in this hand, go into a side pot. This side pot can't be won by the person who is all-in, as they are unable to stake anything to win it. If an all-in bet is itself a raise, it's treated like any other raise, but any future raises beyond that will go into the side pot, as they can't be called by the all-in player. It doesn't matter when in the hand any of this happens, it's treated exactly the same if it's pre-flop or at the river.

Answer (score 0):

> I am so confused with All-In of Limit Holdem.

Lets try to clear your mind. First off shorten your sentence and context to remove the terms "Limit" and "Holdem". Poker is what you are talking about, because simply saying the game is poker means that it has betting rules to it, that are the same for all poker. It does not matter if the game is limit, no limit, Holdem or liars poker. When the game is called poker it means there is betting that includes checking, betting and raising and a community pot. (note lots of things are called poker that are not poker, such as video poker, Chinese poker and games that use what are considered "Poker" hands.)

Poker is simply a game of generally optional betting.

When a player bets you can match the bet, raise the bet or fold. If you cannot match the bet in full, you can only win that part of the bet that you can match. That is the simple basis for every bet, you can only win what part of the bet you have. You cannot win anymore or any less. Your all in call is like any other call. Your done with the hand and get to sit there and watch with no ability to loose or win any more. You call with what part of the bet you can match and you get to win that amount from the bettor and other callers in the hand.

This does not affect the other players at all. Your done you have no stake or claim to any of the other betting that goes on, and the fact that your all in does not stop the other players ability to continue betting and raising. The part you have in the pot is kept separate from any more betting and raising. The other players just keep playing their hands using a side pot. That's really all you need to know, adding anything more confuses a simple concept, that is you only get what you pay for, no more no less.

Beyond that is when a player is raising some amount that is less then a full bet. Whatever they raise they get action on the bet as was hopefully explained above. But the good thing about this rule is that if you have a home game, you get to collectively decide what the rule is, and if your playing in a public card room, they have long ago decided what their rule is and you can just go with the flow and not sweat it. its all explained clearly --- related, possible dupe: poker.stackexchange.com/questions/10011/… – Herb Wolfe